# Can i remove the word "to" in the sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I have read a sentence at the webpage [to in the sentence](https://www.berkshirehathaway.com/donate/webdonat.html):

```
The links below are to letters from Warren E. Buffett dated June 26, 2006
```

Can i remove the `to` in the sentence?

```
The links below are letters from Warren E. Buffett dated June 26, 2006
```

Does `to` here mean `belong to`?

Comment: You cannot remove the word 'to'. It signifies that the links will take anyone who clicks them to the letters of Mr Buffett. If you remove it, you are saying the links **are** those letters, which is nonsense.

Comment: I don't think it really matters whether you include the preposition or not, since the meaning is obvious anyway. And you can be quite sure at least *some* native speakers would *sometimes* drop ***to*** here. But if your text is being *evaluated / judged* (as opposed to just being *read / understood*) you'd better include ***to***, or you'll probably lose marks.

Comment: I can find plenty of examples like "The links below are stories collected from the internet." "The links below are articles of interest that pertain to health, wellness and information on the products and manufacturers we carry". "The links below are articles I have written for The Filipino Expat Magazine". I don't know why you're grammar-checking or editing the website of Berkshire Hathaway though, and it does depend on context/formality.

Comment: I think "to" here is in the sense of "leads to", like "This hallway is to the kitchen". I would drop the "to" here. I think "lead to" and "are" mean approximately the same thing when talking about an internet link. That's a special case, though; you obviously can't say "This hallway is the kitchen"

Comment: I might also say "Here are some links to letters from...", which sounds more normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Simple answer: **No**. The word "link" often pairs with "to," since a "link" is the idea of a connection between two things, like the pieces of a chain. In this internet usage, "link" means a "hyperlink," and by design it has a "target," an address that it directs someone *to*. We also hear "link" paired with "to" in other contexts, like the video game *The Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past*.

  - If we remove the "to," we might alter the meaning. "This road leads to Rome": We're talking about connection. "This road leads Rome": The apparent meaning is nonsense, that the road becomes some kind of leader, directing the city where to go. In your example, removing the "to" from "These links are to letters" means that the links *are* letters.
- More complex answer: **Yes**. At least, in this one example. And maybe you shouldn't. But maybe you could do so without problems. Because sometimes, when one thing *represents* another, we talk about the symbol as if it is the thing it represents. For instance, I could point at my phone screen and say "The blue icon is my email app." Well, no; technically it's an *icon*, not an *app*. Or I might give you a phone number and say "This is my brother; give him a call." No it's not, it's a phone number! But we understand that I'm using a shorthand for "this phone number represents my brother." Similarly, it would be reasonable to say "these links are letters from Mr. Buffet," as an understood shorthand for "this hyperlinks lead to digitized copies of letters." But we can't do this in all situations: "This road *is* Rome" is nonsense. It only works when the connection between two things is *so* established and entrenched that it can be collapsed into "is." And it can be hard to know when this can work and when it can't, and we never *have* to do it. We can always use the longer version, and our meaning will be clearer and safer.